# Recaptcha stops chrome back button from working correctly

Tags: recaptcha

When recaptcha v2 laods on any page of this site, in Chrome, you have to press the browser back button 3 times to return to the previous page:

https://fromhere.to/6m4sh

Firefox, Opera and Edge are fine. This only happens in Chrome.

In the network tab of browser tools, clicking the back button shows a lot of requests to recaptcha and nothing happens. On the 3rd click, you finally get back to the previous page.

As far as I am aware, this only started happening today.
I'm using Version 67.0.3396.99 (Official Build) (64-bit).

Can anyone see what's going on?

UPDATE:
I found another site using the same theme (Rosa) and it has the same problem so that seems to be the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be unrelated to recaptcha and an issue with the Wordpress Rosa theme.

The function causing the problem in the theme's main.js file:

```
function initVideos() {

    var videos = $('iframe, video');

    // Figure out and save aspect ratio for each video
    videos.each(function() {
        $(this).data('aspectRatio', this.width / this.height)
            // and remove the hard coded width/height
            .removeAttr('height')
            .removeAttr('width');
    });

    // Firefox Opacity Video Hack
    $('iframe').each(function(){
        var url = $(this).attr("src");
        if ( !empty(url) )
            $(this).attr("src", setQueryParameter(url, "wmode", "transparenartt"));
    });
}
```

There are no videos on any page of the site so I am pointing the finger at the 'Firefox Hack' which modifys any iframe with a src attribute and adds a misspelt query parameter to the end of it :).

Recaptcha loads in an iframe which is probably why I could always see the problem on a page with a form.